# Windows Server 2008 Remote Access Scenerio

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware, remote-access

I run Windows Server 2008 R2 in my VMWare Fusion. Is there a way to -not locally- remote control the VM using MS' Remote Desktop Connection (or some equivalent tool)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You just need to configure your VM Fusion to listen on Windows Remote Desktop port 3389. You can do this by navigating into file `/VMware Fusion/vmnet8`. There you edit file `nat.conf` With these settings: `[incomingtcp] 3389 = 192.168.0.1:3389`, it is in format `HOST_PORT = VM_IPADDRESS:VM_PORT` So change the VM_IPADRESS properly. Than just restart your VM.